# Angular 4, Using a custom directive to toggle between different HTML templates

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-reactive-forms

We are using a reactive forms and based on some condition,we want a certain fields to be either a free text or dropdown.

I was thinking of ways to implement this functionality and am leaning towards using a custom directive but not sure what solution is best, I am looking for a reusable solution since this will be repeated many times in our application.

I was looking into something like this: [How can I make a structural directive to wrap part of my DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499234/how-can-i-make-a-structural-directive-to-wrap-part-of-my-dom)

I think using renderer would be best option but does it matter if I use attribute or structural directives? They say use structural for modifying Dom but looks like that can be done with attributes as well.

Comment: You can use custom directives if you can reuse it in later components. Considering your use case, I think you must use structural directive i.e. ngIf and that will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it's a good idea to overengineered like that. Don't get me wrong you can write your own custom structural directive and you will probably we able to achieve what you want. But this solution will not scale well. I think that the simplest solution should be the best here. And that is create custom component and bind the variable that will control what is displayed as input.

ifelse.component.html:

```
<mat-radio-group *ngIf="showOne;else other_content" >
  <mat-radio-button value="auto">Auto</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="always">Always</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="never">Never</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
<ng-template #other_content>
  <mat-radio-button value="manual">Manual</mat-radio-button>
<ng-template #other_content></ng-template>
```

ifelse.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-ifelse',
  templateUrl: './ifelse.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ifelse.component.css']
})
export class IfelseComponent {

  @Input()
  private showOne: boolean;

}
```

usage:

```
<app-ifelse [showOne]="false"></app-ifelse>
```